# XML variable type in javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml

I was taking the Javascript aptitude test on oDesk and there was a question that perplexed me:
It asked me this:

> Which of the given options represents the correct length when alert(Emp..*.length()); is applied to the following code?

```
var Emp = <Emp>
  <name>Mark</name>
  <likes>
    <os>Linux</os>
    <browser>Firefox</browser>
    <language>JavaScript</language>
    <language>Python</language>
  </likes>
</Emp>
```

..And then it had some multiple choice answers.  I've never seen anything like this in javascript, and I tried plugging it into my browser and threw an error.  So, why would this be a valid question?  What the hell are they talking about here?

The possible answers are:

a. 11
 b. 5
 c. 6
 d. 12

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure `Emp` isn't a string ? Could you be more precise about `.length()` as in JS a string length is `.length`

Comment: I copied the question verbatim.  It's literally asking what would happen if you typed `alert(Emp..*.length());`.  So far as I know this is completely invalid JS on any platform I can think of.

Comment: Indeed. `String.length()` works in Java, but it may be a redefinition of the `length` method in JS as well. Anyway, `Emp` is weird.

Comment: Looks like Mozilla's [E4X dialect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/E4X) for embedding XML literals in JavaScript. However, `alert(Emp..*.length());` really looks like a syntax error then :-) Maybe you could also list the offered choices?

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is 11. It calculates the number of all descendant elements as well as text nodes.To verify add the code like this:

```
var Emp = <Emp>
  <name>Mark</name>
  <likes>
   <os>Linux</os>
   <browser>Firefox</browser>
   <language>JavaScript</language>
   <language>Python</language>
  </likes>
</Emp>

print("Length: " + Emp..*.length());

var descendants = Emp..*;
for each (var xmlNode in descendants) {
   print(xmlNode.nodeKind() + ': ' + xmlNode.name());
}
```

then the printed result is:

```
Length: 11    
element: name
text: null
element: likes
element: os
text: null
element: browser
text: null
element: language
text: null
element: language
text: null
```

Comment: What language is this? This code throws syntax errors in every version of Javascript I have ever tried (node.js, firefox's spidermonkey, v8 in chrome, etc...)

Comment: That's E4X. Try Rhyno JavaScript.